# Using Underscore.js with ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net, underscore.js

I've been comparing different JavaScript template engines to see which one gives me the best performance for large sets of data.  One that I ran across is [Underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/).  However, I haven't been able to get any of the examples working.  My template looks like:

```
<% _.each(projects(), function(project) { %>
   <tr>
      <td><%= project.code %></td>
      <td><%= project.request %></td>
      <td><%= project.stage %></td>
      <td><%= project.type %></td>
      <td><%= project.launch %></td>
   </tr>
<% }) %>
```

However, when I run the page I get a server-side ASP.NET exception, as it's trying to compile the text within the `<% ... %>` tags:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS1026: ) expected
Line 826:                     <% _.each(projects(), function(project) { %>
```

I was unable to find a way to escape these tags, nor was I able to find a way to configure Underscore to use a different syntax.  Is there a workaround, or are Underscore and ASP.NET simply incompatible with each other?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Same issue with JSP, so we do this:

```
_.templateSettings = {interpolate : /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g,      // print value: {{ value_name }}
                      evaluate    : /\{%([\s\S]+?)%\}/g,   // excute code: {% code_to_execute %}
                      escape      : /\{%-([\s\S]+?)%\}/g}; // excape HTML: {%- <script> %} prints &lt;script&gt;
```

This will allow you to use all the various versions of the tag outputs: interpolation, evaluation and escaping.

Comment: Thanks!  This code helped me a lot..  I got it working, but for some reason there's like a 10-15 second delay when the page loads now..  Not sure what's going on, but the actual binding isn't really any noticeably faster than jQuery.tmpl, so I'll probably go back to using that.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think it's that fast, but since we're using Backbone for our site and have Underscore already installed, might as well use it.  Of course we have jQuery too...

Comment: Ah, the lag went away when I copied the `underscore-min.js` file locally, guess it was on a really slow server.  It actually seems to be a bit quicker with smaller data sets, and about the same for larger datasets.  I might end up keeping it.

Comment: @MikeChristensen yeah, it's not bad at all.  Even it's slowness is countered in my case by the fact that it's always available without loading anything extra.

Answer (score 5):

`<%` are tags used by asp.net. So when the page is parsed, it tries to interpret those but asp.net does not understand the syntax as it expects C# code, not javascript.

You can change the interpolation symbols in the templateSettings to something like `{ }`and `{{ }}`

```
_.templateSettings = {
  interpolate : /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g
  evaluate : /\{(.+?)\}/g; 
};

var template = _.template("Hello {{ name }}!");
template({name : "Mustache"});
=> "Hello Mustache!"
```

**[Documentation](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#template)**

---

FYI, these are the default settings:

```
// By default, Underscore uses ERB-style template delimiters, change the
// following template settings to use alternative delimiters.
_.templateSettings = {
  evaluate    : /<%([\s\S]+?)%>/g,
  interpolate : /<%=([\s\S]+?)%>/g,
  escape      : /<%-([\s\S]+?)%>/g
};
```

Comment: That only fixes one of the tag sets.

Comment: Great!  This was definitely helpful.  `+1`

Answer (score 0):

replace:

```
<% }) %>
```

change for:

```
<% }); %>
```

good luck!!!