# backbone syntax error on my asp.net page <% - %>

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I need to use `<% and %>` but they are reserved for asp.net  so I get a compiler error - how do I fix this

```
  <script type="text/template" id="item-template">
    <div class="view">
      <input class="toggle" type="checkbox">
      <label><%- title %></label>
    </div>
  </script>
```

and this wont work

```
<label><%= "<%-"%> title <%= "%>" %></label>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Underscore.js with ASP.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9724921/using-underscore-js-with-asp-net)

Answer (score 1):

You can change the interpolation symbols for your client side templates in underscore (underscore has the templating stuff used by Backbone).

You can call :

```
_.templateSettings = {interpolate : /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g,      // print value: {{ value_name }}
                  evaluate    : /\{%([\s\S]+?)%\}/g,   // excute code: {% code_to_execute %}
                  escape      : /\{%-([\s\S]+?)%\}/g}; // excape HTML: {%- <script> %} prints &lt;script&gt;
```

[code credit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9724921/using-underscore-js-with-asp-net)

so your code will become :

```
<label>{{ "<%-"%> title <%= "%>" }}</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
<label><&#37;- title &#37;></label>
```

you can use html codes in this cases:

http://ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm